# Retrieve first and last day of the month with Ruby (DateTime)

Tags: ruby, datetime

### How can i retrieve Retrieve first and last day of the month with Ruby (DateTime)?

*I want to create invoices that start the first day and finishes the last day of the month.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `beginning_of_month` and `end_of_month` methods

```
irb(main):004:0> n = DateTime.now
=> Wed, 10 May 2017 14:48:01 +0300
irb(main):005:0> n.to_date.beginning_of_month
=> Mon, 01 May 2017
irb(main):006:0> n.to_date.end_of_month
=> Wed, 31 May 2017
```

Comment: `DateTime.new(n.year, n.month)` and `DateTime.new(n.year, n.month, -1)`

Comment: A comment from 2017: I am not sure if this has been updated recently or if this has always been the case, but it is not necessary to add `.to_date` in order to use the `end/beginning_of_month` methods. You can call them straight on a DateTime object. It would save a step and a conversion to not add `.to_date`

Comment: @Casey But then you are left with a `DateTime` object, not a `Date`, so it will be printed with hours and minutes.

Comment: You're right, @user000001, if one of the requirements was to not show the time, then mine would not pass. I didn't see that as a requirement.

Answer (score 13):

Given a year and a month:

```
year = 2017
month = 5
```

You can pass these to [`Date.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-new) along with a day value of `1` and `-1` to get the first and last day respectively:

```
require 'date'
Date.new(year, month, 1)  #=> #<Date: 2017-05-01 ...>
Date.new(year, month, -1) #=> #<Date: 2017-05-31 ...>
```